# Trying to display the export value of a dropdown menu selection in Adobe PDF

Tags: adobe, dropdown, acrobat

Let me start off by saying I have very limited knowledge of Javascript.

I've got a Dropdown menu called: CustomerType with 6 values in it.

Basically I just want whatever is selected in the dropdown to display again in another part of the PDF.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean " a dropdown menu selection in Adobe PDF", and the relationship with JavaScript ? Do you do it in a html file ? It is better to have more details or add some picture for this question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is missing many important details and information. Please read: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question.

Comment: @Zuckjet - Adobe Acrobat and Reader support JavaScript. It's a very different object model from browsers, but it is based on the core JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 0):

First set the properties on the dropdown to commit the value immediately. See image.
[image]

Then on the "calculate" script for the other field, enter the JavaScript below. You'll need to change the field names to your actual field names.

```
this.getField("myOtherField").value = this.getField("myDropdown").value;
```

You'll want to set the other field to read-only as well since the value is calculated.